# How best to correct poor coding practice which isn't related to the answer

Tags: discussion, questions, code

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588479/event-reciever-for-item-added-is-fired-multiple-times).

How should I let a user know that the code they've written goes against Microsoft's recommended practice? In this case, instantiating an `SPSite` instance with a hardcoded URL, not disposing of `SPSite` when finished and getting an `SPList` instance with the hardcoded list name when it is available in the method parameters.

Normally I'd put it in a comment but that's difficult when it's several lines long. When it's not related to the answer, should I even point this out?

Comment: You could try to put it in the comments in short with a link to the source. And hope that they explain why in the guidelines themself.

Comment: Well, it's stackoverflow, they're coming for a problem they need solved not for a best practices preach. If it was codereview I'd encourage you to point it out but it's not. Maybe add a comment "your code could use some review" and link them to it.

Comment: It helps if you can find a canonical q&a that has all the detail and just link to that.

Comment: I do this on a regular basis to warn about SQL-Injection. You wouldn't believe how many people are still building queries by concatenating constant strings and unescaped user input. So I'd say yes - warn them with a comment even if it's a long one.

Comment: @GillBates - I'd argue that people coming here (for the most part) *do* want to know what they could do better - although I will concede that some flatly do not care.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and I often end up mentioning some of these kinds of things in my answers, but do be aware that sometimes in the process of turning something into an MVCE, best practices that might require more code are dropped in favor of making the question *minimal*.

Comment: Interesting point. Personally if I was abridging code, 9 times out of 10 I'd do so with comments, rather than post bad code to the public internet where it could be copied by some unsuspecting dev. In the SQL injection example I'd probably replace my escaping and parameterising code with a comment like `// Building query here` rather than replace it with quick-and-dirty string concanenation. It won't stop the laziest coders writing dangerous code but it'll force people to go looking for the answer, at least giving them a chance of finding the right one.

Comment: @Mourndark: But then your code won't compile - and for an MCVE, it needs to.  I would certainly encourage people to remove more than the most minimal error checking from an MCVE.

Comment: If you answer, and to not add a warning for poor coding practices even if unrelated to the problem, you could even get downvotes for not noticing them.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, a comment would be appropriate. To give an example, there must be at least [a million comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298290/mysql-is-deprecated-comments-constructive-or-not) in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags along the lines of

> Please note that `mysql_` functions are unsafe and deprecated, rewrite your code to use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Try to find a link where Microsoft's recommended practices are explained so they can read further, but make sure your comment is useful without the link.

Comment: Probably of interest: the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) userscript.